# Different X axes with Plotly's make_subplots

Tags: python, datetime, plotly, candlestick-chart, x-axis

I want to plot two plots with `make_subplots` with different times.
How should I do that?

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1,row_heights=[0.5, 0.5], shared_xaxes=True)

fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x=dfpl.index, open=dfpl['open'], high=dfpl['high'], low=dfpl['low'], close=dfpl['close']), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x=dfDiv.index, open=dfDiv['open'], high=dfDiv['high'], low=dfDiv['low'], close=dfDiv['close']), row=2, col=1)
```

My indexes are different `datetime`s. The chart is shown as below:

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code posted is a subplot and the attached graph is a single graph with no matching content. I don't know exactly what your data is, but my understanding is that you want to draw a subplot based on two data frames and change the display units for the x-axis time series. you can change the display units with dtick. see [here](https://plotly.com/python/time-series/#configuring-tick-labels) for more information on x-axis time series. If you want to change the range of the x-axis, use range. Specify the start and end dates in a list format. See [here](https://plotly.com/python/time-series/#time-series-plot-with-custom-date-range) for more information.

```
import yfinance as yf
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import datetime

dfaapl = yf.download("AAPL", start="2021-01-01", end="2024-01-01")
dfgoog = yf.download("GOOG", start="2021-01-01", end="2024-01-01")

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1,
                    row_heights=[0.45, 0.45],
                    vertical_spacing=0.4,
                    shared_xaxes=False)

fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x=dfaapl.index,
                             open=dfaapl['Open'],
                             high=dfaapl['High'],
                             low=dfaapl['Low'],
                             close=dfaapl['Close'],
                             name='AAPL'), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x=dfgoog.index,
                             open=dfgoog['Open'],
                             high=dfgoog['High'],
                             low=dfgoog['Low'],
                             close=dfgoog['Close'],
                             name='GOOG'), row=2, col=1)
fig.update_layout(height=450, margin=dict(t=20,b=0,l=0,r=0))
fig.update_xaxes(dtick='M3',tickformat="%b\n%Y", row=1,col=1)
fig.update_xaxes(range=[datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1), datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 31)],
                 tickformat="%m\n%Y", row=2,col=1)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply.my data is a single pair in two timeframe(aapl in 4h and 1h .1000 candle)

Comment: Try applying your data with my code. Then add to your question what you want the x axis to look like. Your question is a little unclear on the goal.